# Need help testing a method in liferay api/jsonws

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I'm trying to test a function from the api/jsonws in liferay 7.3.5-ga6.

The function I'm trying to test is "update-group" from the class GroupLocalServiceUtil. I'm running into a problem when filling in the variables. Specifically, the "nameMap" and "descriptionMap". These variables are in the "java.util.map" datatype and I'm struggling to figure out what exactly to fill in here.
I want to use this function to update a site(group) in liferay programmatically.

Does anyone know what I need to fill in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the signature of the method behind `update-group` api/jsonws

Look at GroupServiceImpl class.

```
public Group updateGroup(
        long groupId, long parentGroupId, Map<Locale, String> nameMap,
        Map<Locale, String> descriptionMap, int type,
        boolean manualMembership, int membershipRestriction,
        String friendlyURL, boolean inheritContent, boolean active,
        ServiceContext serviceContext)
    throws PortalException {
```

Try the following json in the nameMap parameter:

```
{
 "it_IT":"name it",
 "fr_FR":"name fr"
}
```